# Verify that any online service is secure

Tags: credit-card, cloud-storage

I personally don't trust cloud storage, I understand the convenience, but it's not enough for me. Is there any way other than the company saying so, to verify that the storage of my files is indeed encrypted, so that it's safe and secure? 
[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/security/physical-location-data-storage) says so, but obviously there is no way for me to verify it. I guess this [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101192/can-we-determine-how-securely-files-are-stored-on-a-cloud-storage-service) sums up what I'm looking for.

Same goes for companies that allow storage of credit cards. I personally try not to use my credit card online, and even if I have an account with an online store, I don't store it. Do companies that accept credit cards as payment have to pass a security audit before they can safely accept and store credit cards?

Comment: "I guess this [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101192/can-we-determine-how-securely-files-are-stored-on-a-cloud-storage-service) sums up what I'm looking for." I'm confused. If that question is a good summary what you want to ask, isn't this question just a duplicate of that one?

Comment: Encrypt it yourself before you send it to the cloud. That way it is just a blob sitting on Dropbox etc.

Comment: For payment cards, see https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/